# Does Ehrenfest Urn Model has Markov property and independent increment

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

$Y_t = X_t + X_{t−1}$, where $X_t$ is defined as Ehrenfest Urn Model has 6 black balls. My concerns how to prove $Y_t$ has not have a Markov property. I have take some real case and I realise that it only depends on $X_t$ on $X_{t-1}$ but I do not how to prove it.

One more thing is about independent increment how could we prove or disprove it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).